Accessing value of specific arrayed objects that are fetched from API - javascript
I made similar question, but it's not solving my problem. I have an object that I'm getting from API using fetch().
When I console.log() fetched data, I get this for example:
let fetchData = {
  type: "string",
  id: 123,
  included: [
    {
      type: "wanted-type",
      attributes: { stats: { name: "name1" } }
    }, {
      type: "not-wanted-type",
      id: 111
    }, {
      type: "wanted-type",
      attributes: { stats: { name: "name2" } }
    }]
}

First I tried to access desired value like this "fetchData.included.find(value => value.attributes.stats.name === "name1) but then I realized not all objects in array have "attributes" key. So I used filter method to gather all objects with type of "wanted-type" into another array and I made it. It looked like this:
let arrayFetch = fetchData.included;
let array = [];
const result = arrayFetch.filter(res => res.type === "wanted-type");
if(result) {
  array.push(result);
}

It successfully push desired data into "array", but when I later try to access anything, it says it's undefined. For example:
console.log(array[0].attributes) or
console.log(array[0].attributes.stats.name)



it says "undefined".
Can you please help?

Observe what result and array are after this:
const result = arrayFetch.filter(res => res.type === "wanted-type");
if(result) {
  array.push(result);
}

Since result is an array, then array is an array of arrays.  So this won't work:
console.log(array[0].attributes)

Because an array has no property called attributes.  This could work:
console.log(array[0][0].attributes)

But instead of digging into the structure you have, use a better structure.  Why push result into a new array in the first place?  Just use result directly:
let arrayFetch = fetchData.included;
const result = arrayFetch.filter(res => res.type === "wanted-type");
console.log(result[0].attributes);


update: yes! that's it, thanks a lot
